# Trouble with returning and displaying values in integer arrays - Java

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to create an integer array of 30 elements using a Random class and a loop to fill the array with numbers between 0 and 49.

The program should then ask the user to provide a number between 0 and 49 and return this value in a separate method and then use another loop to review the array and display every number with a message as to whether the number in the array element is greater than, equal to or less than the number provided by the user.

What I have so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class MethodTest 
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
   // Arrays
   int[] num = new int[30];
   int randomNumber;
   int userNumber;


   getValues(num);


   for(int x = 0; x < num.length; x++)
   {
   Random r = new Random();
   randomNumber = r.nextInt(50);
   System.out.println(num[x] + randomNumber);
   }

   for(int x = 0; x < num.length; x++)
   {
   System.out.println("The number " + getHigh(num) + "is greater than: " + userNumber);
   }

   for(int x = 0; x < num.length; x++)
   {
   System.out.println("The number " + getLow(num) + "is less than: " + userNumber);
   }

   for(int x = 0; x < num.length; x++)
   {
   System.out.println("The number " + getEqual(num) + "is equal to: " + userNumber);
   }
}

   public static void getValues(int[] array)
   {
   Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
   int userNumber;
   System.out.print("Enter a number between 0 and 49: ");
   userNumber = kb.nextInt();

   return userNumber;
   }

   public static void getHigh(int[] num)
   {
   int high = num[0];
   for(int x = 0; x < num.length; x++) 
      {
      if(num[x] > userNumber)
      high = num[x];
      }
   return high;
   }

   public static void getLow(int[] num)
   {
   int low = num[0];
   for(int x = 0; x < num.length; x++) 
      {
      if(num[x] > userNumber)
      low = num[x];
      }
   return low;
   }

   public static void getEqual(int[] num)
   {
   int equal = num[0];
   for(int x = 0; x < num.length; x++) 
      {
      if(num[x] == userNumber)
      equal = num[x];
      }
   return equal;

   }
}
```

I am failing to understand how to return the values that will display the relation between the user's number and the numbers from the array. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You could start by changing `public static void getValues(int[] array)` to something more like `public static int getValues()` ... pretty sure you don't need to pass the array to this method as it's not using it

Comment: **Never** create your `Random` **inside** a loop body. You are ***guaranteeing*** you won't get randomized values.

Comment: Make sure you initialize your `new Random()` outside of the loop. Otherwise you'll create a bunch of new Random instances using the same time seed, and ask each one for the first value, which will almost always be the same.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Looking through your code, it appears there are a number of problems with it, including some that would produce compile-time errors. Please break down your problem into small pieces that can be expressed with a minimal code example, and which are likely to have a single correct answer. Then ask each of these smaller questions as separate posts on StackOverflow. Not only will you get better answers this way, but you may also find the answer to your questions on your own in the process.

Comment: Your question, how to display the relation, is step 2.  Step 1 is to fill the array with random numbers.  Verify step 1 works before moving on to step 2.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly not sure how to what you are asking but this is how to code the assignment, let me know if you need help.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class main{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Random r = new Random();
        int[] nums = new int[30];
        for(int i=0;i<30;i++){
            nums[i]=r.nextInt(50);
        }
        check(nums);
    }
    public static void check(int[] nums){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter an integer between 0 and 49");
        System.out.println();
        int x = in.nextInt();
        for(int i: nums){
            if(i<x) System.out.println("The number " +x+ " is greater than " + i+ ".");
            else if(i>x) System.out.println("The number " +x+ "is less than " + i+ ".");
            else if(i==x) System.out.println("The number " +x+ "is equal to " + i+ ".");
        }
    }
}
```